# How to run php artisan migrate on a db with a lot of tables and data without previous migrations in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I have created a lot of tables and I have a lot of data in my db's tables already.

I haven't used migrations so far. But right now I would like to, in this case where I need to set foreign keys using this code:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('role_user', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

But If I run `php artisan migrate` I get this error:

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL
  : alter table `role_user` add constraint role_user_role_id_foreign foreign
  key (`role_id`) references `roles` (`id`) on delete cascade)



migrate [--bench[="..."]] [--database[="..."]] [--force] [--path[="..."]] [--pac
kage[="..."]] [--pretend] [--seed]
```

I have roles and users table already and `id` is set as the `primary key`.

Any idea how to make this auto creation of the table from the schema in the migration file in my db happen?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/bruceoutdoors/9166186

Comment: The fact that it throws `General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint` makes me think it's probably from your `role_user.role_id` and `roles.id` are incompatible types. What are their types?

Comment: @Unnawut The `id` column in my `roles` table is `INT`, `10` characters long `UNSIGNED` and it's a `PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: Oh well I can't be of further help then. I think it's worth updating your question with the column types too though.